# Can an iOS app read its own entitlements at runtime?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, keychain, code-signing-entitlements

Can an iOS app discover, inspect, or otherwise read its own entitlements at runtime?

Ideally, I could read the whole (processed) contents of my .entitlements file as a plist. Getting just the app identifier prefix would be an acceptable second-best.

Goals here include: allowing the app to be signed with various app identifier prefixes, without needing to make a matching change in code; and to act differently in the presence or absence of shared keychain access groups. This is library code, so the less I impose on the client app's configuration, the better.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]

Comment: @rgeorge. did you find the right answer of your question?

Comment: Nope! The closest answer involves copying the build .entitlements file, which doesn't capture the actual entitlements compiled into the executable, which is what I really needed. A radar is long since filed but I'm not holding my breath.

Comment: did you find any solution @rgeorge

Comment: You might be interested in `SecTaskLoadEntitlements`

Answer (score 9):

In short, no. The entitlements file is only used at compile-time and is not copied into the app bundle.

**Clarification**: During development, the entitlements are written into the `embedded.mobileprovision` file in the app bundle. When your app is released as an IPA on the App Store, it will not contain a `embedded.mobileprovision`.

Comment: Is this true? I think codesign bakes them into the app's executable. When you do `codesign -d --entitlements :- MyApp.app` it will display the embedded entitlements.

Comment: @MartijnThé That's because you're running it on the desktop, so it's not at _runtime_ like the question asked. During development, the entitlements are written into the `embedded.mobileprovision` file in the app bundle. When your app is released as an IPA in the App Store, it will not contain a `embedded.mobileprovision`. You can check this yourself. Just open any IPA you find in your iTunes folder using the `Archive Utility`, go the `Payload` folder, `Show Package Contents` on the app bundle and inspect its contents.

Comment: I think the codesign tool looks at the binary file and not the embedded.mobileprovision. 1) If you remove the embedded.mobileprovision file codesign still works 2) If you run codesign against a build downloaded from the App Store it still works 3) if you look in the binary file you can find the entitlements. With it in the binary I sure wish there was a way to access it at runtime too.

Answer (score 5):

As others mentioned in comments, the signed executable of your app contains an embedded entitlements plist, which suggests it should be possible.

You will need to use some non-ios-public ([but](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1400321-sectaskcreatefromself?language=objc) [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1393461-sectaskcopyvalueforentitlement?language=objc)) APIs. Try the following code:

```
// Declare the private SecTask functions in your header file
void* (SecTaskCopyValueForEntitlement)(void* task, CFStringRef entitlement, CFErrorRef  _Nullable *error);
void* (SecTaskCreateFromSelf)(CFAllocatorRef allocator);


// And call it in your code like this:
CFErrorRef err = nil;
NSArray* groups = SecTaskCopyValueForEntitlement(SecTaskCreateFromSelf(NULL), CFSTR("com.apple.security.application-groups"), &err);
```

Comment: They're documented for OSX, not for iOS. If you use them your app gets rejected.

Comment: I needed to change the NSArray * to CFTypeRef in order for it to work...

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, you can do it. For example, In order to read `YourFileName.entitlements` and get AppGroup ID, please follow below steps:

Step 1: Add your `.entitlements` to your target by `"Copy Bundle Resources"`

Step 2: Using below source code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourFileName"
                                                 ofType:@"entitlements"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *suiteName =  [[dict objectForKey:@"com.apple.security.application-groups"] firstObject]; // It's your data
```

Comment: This isn't really valid... you're copying the entitlements file into your application bundle, but it may not reflect the actual entitlements of your application at runtime.

Comment: Who needs run-time; one may simply need Merchant-ID and similar (which are forced to be listed in Entitlements file).

Comment: However, adding to copy bundle produces a warning, hence, use following approach instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56044915/8740349