# Is it possible to read entitlements files in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, readfile, entitlements

I am implementing universal deep linking in my app. When I registered my different domains, it creates an AppName.entitlements file

I would like to read the values of this file like a plist.

I tried

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("AppName", ofType:
"entitlements") { }
```

but it returns `nil`

Is it possible to read such files?

Comment: `nil` means the file couldn't be located. Check the "Discussion" section in [the docs for this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:) so you can see the approach it uses to find the file. Make sure the file is locatable by that algorithm (and that you spelled everything correctly). Especially note: *"It does not recurse through other subfolders at any of these locations"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That file isn't copied in to your app (see Xcode's target checkbox). It is only used for building

the entitlements are a config file for Xcode

so: **no**

> **Note** that even if you add it manually to your bundle, it produces a warning similar to:
> [Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3095612)
>
> Workaround said warning like:
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56044915/8740349

Comment: yeah it makes sense. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found:

add the `appGroup` into `Info.Plist` file

```
<key>appGroup</key>
<string>group.com.acronis.mobile.ios.development</string>
```

To read the string use the code below:

```
extension String {

    // MARK: - Static

    static var appGroup: String = {
        guard let bundleAppGroup = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["appGroup"] as? String else {
            fatalError("The application must contain appGroup in Info.plist file")
        }
        return bundleAppGroup
    }()
}
```

Change the `entitlements` and `Info.plist` at before build time using your custom script if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I dove into this subject a bit and it is actually quite simple.

You use a run script to grab the entitlements and merge it into Info.plist:

```sh
ENTITLEMENTS= # Path to Project.entitlements #
INFOPLIST= # Path to Info.plist #
echo "Writing entitlements to Info.plist"; 
KEY="entitlements-from-script"; 
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "delete $KEY" "$INFOPLIST"; 
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add $KEY dict" "$INFOPLIST"; 
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "merge $ENTITLEMENTS $KEY" "$INFOPLIST";
```

Now you can use it in code:

```swift
let entitlements = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["entitlements-from-script"]
```

Comment: Nice tool! Seems to be by default installed on MacOS (but only works with full-path, by default).

Answer (score 0):

While looking into this I found the following blog post
https://medium.com/swlh/reading-application-entitlements-with-swift-65cff184e840
where @mateuszmatrejek explains how to parse the binary file at run time to extract the entitlements.

This approach is very low level and complex. The key advantage I see with this approach is if you are working on a framework or library this would work to read the entitlements of the app which is using importing your lib or framework.